# Taxonomy archive page listing terms instead of posts

Tags: plugin-development, query, advanced-taxonomy-queries

Is it possible to show list of taxonomy terms in archive page instead of the post list? Via modifying the query and not temper with theme templates?

I have a taxonomy archive that I want to display list of terms from another taxonomy, because they are linked via term meta.

Is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without messing with templates, no.

All WordPress pages are based on a query for a post or posts. If you want to list terms the only way to do that is a custom template that queries the terms and lists them.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I've been googling this enough to agree. 

Thousand thanks for you reply nonetheless. :)